# Gridview inside scrollview not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-gridview, android-scrollview

I am trying to design a layout as shown in below image. It contains an `ImageView` for cover image, `GridView` in which each cell will act as a button for performing various actions and below that `TextView` as footer.

[image: Layout Image]

I am not able to achieve this thing. Below is my `xml` code:

`home.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/xyz" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"></GridView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="OSKAR" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`singlegrid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:background="#ffffff"
     android:orientation="vertical">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am struggling with this issue and searched a lot with various solutions but not able to find out the correct one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this four (button with icon) would be fix? or it will increment?

Comment: The number of grids is fixed i.e. 10 grids (button with icon). Initially I want to display 4 and remaining will be appearing as we scroll on the screen

Answer (score 1):

I think Why should you use scrollView?
Without scrollview your requirement satisfied.

you can set height of grid's child dyanamically like below:

```
Child_item_height= 
(screenheight - (toolbar_height+imageview_height+footer_height+textview_height))/2
```

**Note:** you can set textview height fix like 20dp.
Using above login you can get height of grid so that you can display 4 grid in screen and another grid in scroll.